# dgv does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

```
public partial class Form7 : Form
{
    private MySqlDataAdapter da;
    private MySqlConnection conn;
    BindingSource bsource = new BindingSource();
    DataSet ds = null;
    string sql; 

    public Form7()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost;database=d1; uid=root; password=123;port=3307;";
        conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        sql = "SELECT Name, Address, id, Status FROM t1";

        da = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
        conn.Open();
        ds = new DataSet();
        MySqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(da);
        da.Fill(ds, "Orders");
        bsource.DataSource = ds.Tables["Orders"];
        dgv.DataSource = bsource;
    }
}
```

It is giving me an error call:

```
dgv does not exist in the current context
```

What can I do to fix it? Should I use any packages or something?

Answer (score 1):

From your code it seems that you are missing the `dgv` object,  something like: `private DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();`

See the [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx) section from msdn.

Comment: where should I insert that statement??/

Comment: @user1724557 Along with the rest of the fields (da, conn, ...), see the example from my link.

Answer (score 0):

Check your markup file (it could be file type *.ascx or *.aspx) and make sure that you actually called your DataGrid object "dgv". I've had the exact error before and it was due to misspelling of the object name. Just copy and paste the name from the markup file into your code file to make sure you've got the right spelling!

Answer (score -1):

It could be the problem with the markup file. if you are using windows forms host with a datagridview in wpf window, then is probably due to namespace resolution. use x:Name instead of Name for giving it a name in the xaml.